# Get group name with count if Null mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the count of status as 0 which is not present in the table:

Mytable:

```
id   |    status    |
----------------------
1         Open      
2         Closed    
3         Closed
4         Open
----------------------
```

Expecting Result:

```
statusname   |    statuscount   |
---------------------------------
Open              2
Closed            2
Cancelled         0
Rejected          0
---------------------------------
```

I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(status), status FROM in_e_s_s__p_c_ns
WHERE status IN ("Open","Closed","Rejected","Cancelled") GROUP BY status
```

Comment: How did you get statusname   "Cancelled" and "Rejected" in the expected output how does this related to the example data? There isn't anny  "Cancelled" and "Rejected" there.. Or are  "Cancelled" and "Rejected" generated with the `IN ("Open","Closed","Rejected","Cancelled")` meaning it should be dynamic?

Comment: I am using above four status. If status name Cancelled and Rejected is not present in the table it should be take it as 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a delivered table approach and a LEFT JOIN for this to work.

```
SELECT 
   status_records.status AS statusname
 , COUNT(*) AS statuscount   
FROM (

  SELECT 
   'Open' AS status
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
   'Closed' AS status
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
   'Rejected' AS status
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
   'Cancelled' AS status
) AS status_records

LEFT JOIN 
 myTable
ON
 status_records.status = myTable.status
GROUP BY
 status_records.status
```